# Acts As Taggable On taggable_id incrementing so fast

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-taggable-on

I retrieved 54 items from my database:

```
items = Item.where(condition)
items.count == 54
and then:
items.each {|i| i.tag_list.add("tag")}
```

But:

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging.pluck(:taggable_id)
```

Returns this array of `taggable_id`:

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 9, 9, 15, 15, 18, 18, 24, 25, 25, 32, 32, 38, 38, 49, 49, 74, 74, 93, 93, 96, 96, 99, 99, 363, 363, 583, 583, 854, 926, 926, 939, 939, 5276, 5276, 22118, 22118, 48474, 48474, 80172, 624486, 624486, 28184633, 28184633]
```

When te item count is > 100 the taggable_id goes out of range and raises an exception. As it's trying to insert a 12 digits integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to the `taggable_id` being an hexadecimal string instead of an integer. When the rails parsed the number to integer it becomes a `bigint`.

`ActsAsTaggableOn` is not accepting (at this moment) strings as a foreign taggable_ids.